# How to connect dbeaver with docker instance of mysql locally

Tags: mysql, docker, dbeaver

i have ran those commands:

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e 
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6
```

then

```
 docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS      NAMES
35da304532c8   mysql:5.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   3306/tcp   mysql-standalone
    docker exec -it mysql-standalone bash
    root@35da304532c8:/# mysql -uroot -p -A
    Enter password:
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 6
    Server version: 5.6.51 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    
    Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.
    
    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
    
    mysql>
```

but while trying to connect via dbeaver i get somethins like this

[image]

where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop your existing mysql container and remove it with:

```
docker stop <container id>
docker rm <container id>
```

Then run container again with port mapping. Use `-p 3306:3306` to map container port into host machine port.

The full command will be like this:

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.6
```

This time dbeaver connection should work.

**Explanation**
Your mysql server is running in port 3306 inside the docker container. This port is **inside** that container, not your host machine. Dbeaver does not know about that container, it tries to connect with your host machine (your laptop/pc) port. Using `-p 3306:3306` you map the container port with your computers port.